# Is XCGLogger thread safe?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, logging, xcglogger

I am considering using `XCGLogger` to replace CocoaLumberjack and would like to know if is it permissible to log the following from any thread using a global logger created and setup on the main thread as per the README?

```
log.info("This is not a valid format: \(inputStr)")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes, `XCGLogger` is thread safe, but it uses `println()` which itself it's thread safe, so other callers of `println()` can make it appear as if `XCGLogger` itself isn't.

`XCGLogger` uses a queue to ensure all `println()` it calls are called and completed in a thread safe manner.

Note however that if you call `println()` directly from elsewhere in your app, or another library does, those calls are not thread safe and could still interfere with the calls from `XCGLogger`.

There's a unit test in the project (`testMultiThreaded`) that shows multiple calls to `XCGLogger` through a concurrent queue and they all write safely. But you can see that Xcode itself outputs information about the tests as they're running and that output can become tangled with the log output.